# How to create a new thread when an existing one crashes in java

Tags: java, spring

I have to maintain a series of java thread classes in legacy code.
The threads are created through spring initialization at startup of a web server.

Their run method have an infinite loop and work done in the loop
can throw a few exceptions (sql connection exceptions for example because the db is unreachable say)

Something like this

```
  public class MyThread extends Thread implements InitializingBean {
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
           while(true) {
              // do work
           }
        }
        catch (final SQLException se) {
                // do some error handling
            }
        finally {
           // clean up resources
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that if there is an exception the thread ends. I would like the thread to either stay alive or create a new thread and try again.

What is the best practice here?
To create a new Thread?
How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

No, just wrap a `while (true) {}` around it. If you really do need abilities to programmatically end this thread permanently, you'd use `while (!Thread.interrupted()) {}` instead and ensure you return (i.e. end the thread) in the `catch (InterruptedException e) {}` block. Then, simply call `.interrupt()` on your thread to eventually kill it (an interruption results in *either* that `Thread.interrupted()` returning true exactly once, *or* an InterruptedException. Hence, ensure you break off your thread either way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the single thread pool and submit a runnable task to the pool. If an exception occurs the current thread gets terminated and a new one is created.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like the thread to either stay alive or create a new thread and try again.

(A) To stay alive, add an outer `while` loop as discussed in [Answer by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76006016/642706).

(B) To get the effect of starting again, an alternative to starting a new thread is to rewrite your code to use the Executors framework added to Java 5. In modern Java, we rarely address the `Thread` class directly.

Write your task as a class implementing `Runnable`. Add a constructor that takes an `ExecutorService` object as an argument.

```java
class DatabaseReporter implements Runnable 
{
    private final ExecutorService executerService ;

    DatabaseReporter ( final ExecutorService es ) {
        this.executerService = es ;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
           while(true) {
              // do work
           }
        }
        catch (final SQLException se) {
                // do some error handling
            }
        finally {
           // clean up resources
           // clean up any ThreadLocal uses. 
           this.executorService.submit( new DatabaseReporter( this.executorService ) ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Obtain a single-threaded executor service by calling `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`.

Keep a reference to your executor service. You must perform a graceful shutdown of your executor service before your app ends. Otherwise your backing thread pool may continue indefinitely like a zombie ‍♂️. Or, if in a Jakarta EE environment, use a managed executor service.

Beware of any use you may have made of `ThreadLocal`. Since an executor service recycles threads, any previously set `ThreadLocal` values remain.

In the future, when Project Loom succeeds, Java will gain virtual threads. When using virtual threads, the issue of leftover `ThreadLocal` goes away.